# Confused by loss of float precision in financial application with python Decimal package

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, finance

I'm having a problem in financial application when calculate `70000.0*5.65500*18.0/36000.0` and compare the result with another number.

The accurate result is 197.925

When use Decimal, the results depends on operation order:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from fractions import Fraction
Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')*Decimal('18.0')/Decimal('36000.0')

The result is Decimal('197.925000')

Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')/Decimal('36000.0')*Decimal('18.0')

The result is Decimal('197.9249999999999999999999999')
```

When use Decimal + Fraction, the results are still inaccurate:

```
Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')*Decimal(float(Fraction(18, 36000)))

The result is Decimal('197.9250000000000041201417278')
```

When use the native float, the operation order does not affect the results while results are still inaccurate:

```
Decimal(70000.0*5.65500*18.0/36000.0)

The result is Decimal('197.92500000000001136868377216160297393798828125')

Decimal(70000.0/36000.0*5.65500*18.0)

The result is Decimal('197.92500000000001136868377216160297393798828125')
```

And by treat `Decimal(1.0/36000.0)` or `Decimal(5.655/36000.0)` as a multiplier, the order almost does not affect the results while results are still inaccurate:

```
Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')*Decimal('18.0')*Decimal(1.0/36000.0)

The result is Decimal('197.9250000000000094849096025')

Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')*Decimal(1.0/36000.0)*Decimal('18.0')

The result is Decimal('197.9250000000000094849096026')

Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal(5.655/36000.0)*Decimal('18.0')

The result is Decimal('197.9250000000000182364540136')

Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('18.0')*Decimal(5.655/36000.0)

The result is Decimal('197.9250000000000182364540136')
```

If there is no method to achieve absolute accurate, a fault-tolerance maybe is a way out: Compare two number within a fault-tolerance.

The native float have precision of 1E-14

```
Decimal(70000.0/36000.0*5.65500*18.0) - Decimal('197.925000')

The result is Decimal('1.136868377216160297393798828E-14')
```

The Decimal of default setting have precision of 1E-25

```
Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')/Decimal('36000.0')*Decimal('18.0') - Decimal('197.925000')

The result is Decimal('-1E-25')
```

The precision of Decimal can be set by user

```
import decimal as decimal
from decimal import Decimal, Context
decimal.setcontext(Context(prec=60))
Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')/Decimal('36000.0')*Decimal('18.0')

The result is Decimal('197.924999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999')


Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')*Decimal('18.0')/Decimal('36000.0')

The result is Decimal('197.925000')


Decimal(70000.0/36000.0*5.65500*18.0) - Decimal('197.925000')

The result is Decimal('1.136868377216160297393798828125E-14')


Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')/Decimal('36000.0')*Decimal('18.0') - Decimal('197.925000')

The result is  Decimal('-1E-57')
```

In financial applications, in order to ensure absolute security, is there a recommended fault-tolerance? Does the default Decimal precision with fault-tolerance of 1E-20 enough?

Comment: What would you expect as the result for `Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')/Decimal('36000.0')`?

Answer (score 2):

Just like floating-point arithmetic does generally, [Python's Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is not exact and is subject to round-off error. Compared to `float`, the key difference with Decimal is that it uses a base-10 representation, so that values like "0.1" are exactly representable.

In your first example,

```
Decimal('70000.0')*Decimal('5.65500')/Decimal('36000.0')*Decimal('18.0')

The result is Decimal('197.9249999999999999999999999')
```

In this computation, Decimal is using its default precision of 28 places. Note that the result is printed with 28 significant digits, and is correct up to an off-by-one difference in the lowest digit. In other words, the computation has a round-off error of 1 ["units in the last place" (ULP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place). It is typical that an expression involving a handful of floating-point operations comes out with a few ULPs of round-off error. So this is working as intended.

I see you have already tried [increasing Decimal's precision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#floating-point-notes). This reduces the magnitude of the round-off error, but yes, there is still round-off error.

If you don't like to see the trailing "9"s on the end of the printed result, use for instance `round(result, 12)` to round away the bottom few digits.

Or if exact computation is a must, which I could understand for a financial application, then don't use Decimal or other float-point representations. Reformulate the computation as arithmetic with Fractions:

```
Fraction(70000) * Fraction(5655, 1000) * Fraction(18) / Fraction(36000)
```

This exactly produces the correct answer, 7917/40 = 197.925.

See also the Python documentation [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).